# JQuery Slicknav, merge two menus in one, but on 2 columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile, slicknav

on a wordpress custom theme, I'm using slicknav menu to create a responsive mobile menu.
It works great, so I decide to merge the second menu present on my site (category menu) in the mobile menu.
Using this [codePen](http://codepen.io/ComputerWolf/pen/tjyIg) it's simple and easy, but I'd like to separate the menus in two floating columns, left category and right the global menu.

see image:
[image]
I currently can insert a "`<hr>`" between one menu and the other, using `combinedMenu.append("<hr>");`, but if I "append" to create the float `combinedMenu.append("<div class='col-sm-6'>");` the resulting code is

```
<li><a>.....</a></li>
<li><a>.....</a></li>
<div class='col-sm-6'></div>
<li><a>.....</a></li>
```

so it closes the tag itself! GRRRRR

can anyone helps me?

bye, L.